# Proof the $f=0,a.e$ if $\int_p^qf=0$

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem**: If $f\in L^1[0,1]$, for any rational pairs $0\leq p<q\leq 1$, the integral $\int_p^qf(x)dx=0$. Show $f(x)=0,a.e. $on $[0,1]$.

My try: $g(t)=\int_0^tf(x)dx,t\in[0,1]$, then $g(t)=0$ at all rational points. For any real number, exists $\{t_n\}\rightarrow t$, then we can approximate any points(**is this right ?**) . Then $g(t)=0$, and $\int_0^tf(x)dx$ is differential almost everywhere. $f(x)=g'=0$, almost everywhere.

Is this try right?

Any help proving this problem? Thanks

Comment: Here's something slightly better: if $f$ is measurable, its integral is continuous. $g(t) = 0$ for every rational $0 < t < 1$ and is continuous, so what can you say?

Comment: @CameronWilliams so we can say $\lim g(t_n)=g(t)$. but why $f$ measurable implies integral continuous (**or may be we need add a.e.**)?

Comment: Doh I meant in $L^1$. Not sure why I said measurable. See Folland's _Real Analysis_ Section 2.3, problem 26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under our condition, we claim that 
$$\int_Ef=0\text{ for all measurable set $E\subseteq[0,1]$}$$

First, each open intervals is intersection of countable rational intervals, by continuity and Dominate convergence theorem, $\int_x^yf=0\forall 0\leq x<y\leq 1$ then each open set $\mathcal{O}$ is disjoint countable union of open intervals. By countable additivity of integral, $\int_\mathcal{O}f=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\int_{x}^yf=0$, then $G_\delta$ set is countable intersection of open sets, again by continuity and dominated convergence theorem,$\int_Gf=0$. Then each measurable set of finite measure can be approximated by $G_\delta$ set, that means there is a $G_\delta$ set $G$ containing $E$ and $m(G-E)=0$, so $\int_Ef=\int_Gg=0$.

Then consider $E^+=\{x\in[0,1]|f(x)\geq 0\},E^-=\{x\in[0,1]|f(x)\leq 0\}$, both measurable. so $$\int_{[0,1]}f^+=\int_{E^+}f=0$$ so $f^+=0,a.e$, similarly, $f^-=0,a.e.$, hence $f=f^+-f^-=0,a.e. \square$